# Which version of my parameterized SSIS connection string will be used when deploying the project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm creating an SSIS package in which I want to use the Configuration Manager to switch between my development and production server when loading data. I will only need to do this during development (when I'm changing table designs and such).

I've got the project working, and it's using a variable I put in Project.params to change the server appropriately when I choose "Development" or "Production" from the Visual Studio dropdown. (I did this by parameterizing the connection manager.)

My question is: **how does SSIS know which mode to use when I deploy the project?** I have read that these Configuration choices only apply to running manually in Visual Studio, which is fine, but then which connection string will it use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: it doesn't. At least, it doesn't know how. So, you have to set it.

Set the connection string in as a package Parameter and then map that parameter to an environment variable on the SSIS Server. The environment variable should point to the correct instance in each environment that you promote through. This means that there will be environment variables for each server instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer. I like J. Weezy's answer better because it doesn't involve hard-coding a value in a single place, but I wanted to include this also because it's a possibility for quick testing.

Without taking additional steps the package will not have values set for any parameterized items configured as noted in the question.

What you can do to set default values for these items is go to your project under Integration Services Catalogs, right click the project, select "Configure...", and enter what you want the default value(s) to be for any project parameters on the Parameters tab, like so:

[SSIS Project Configuration Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzio2.png)

(In my example, the parameter value I'm setting is ServerName on a ConnectionManager.)

I found this answer on the following page:

[Integration Services (SSIS) Package and Project Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-2017)